# Reading a text file in java

Tags: java, file-io

How would I read a .txt file in Java and put every line in an array when every lines contains integers, strings, and doubles? And every line has different amounts of words/numbers.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, what exactly do you wanna do with each line ?

Comment: This question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224952

Comment: @Fabian Steeg: The question you linked to doesn't address dealing with different data types like this one does.

Comment: @Bemrose, I'm not exactly sure what the author of the question means, but I understand it as *where every line can contain different kinds and amounts of numbers*. But yeah, I don't know.

Answer (score 12):

Try the [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class which no one knows about but can do almost anything with text.

To get a reader for a file, use

```
File file = new File ("...path...");
String encoding = "...."; // Encoding of your file
Reader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (
    new FileInputStream (file), encoding));

... use reader ...

reader.close ();
```

You should really specify the encoding or else you will get strange results when you encounter umlauts, Unicode and the like.

Comment: "No one knows about Scanner". atleast held true for me. The scanner can also be used as:      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("fileName"));    //any idea why not to use it this way?

Comment: @sttaq: Because that uses the default encoding. Never use the default encoding when reading data. Always find out what the input is or specify what encoding your code accepts; in either way, nail it down to something specific.

Comment: 'No-one knows about it' is sheer nonsense, as is 'can do almost anything with text'. Don't make pointless and extravagant claims.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest option is to simply use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) JAR and import the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils class. There are many possibilities when using this class, but the most obvious would be as follows;

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("untitled.txt"));
```

It's that easy.

> "Don't reinvent the wheel."

Comment: This method appears to now be deprecated. Specifying a charset is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to read a file in `Java` is to open in, read line by line and process it and close the strea

```
// Open the file
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

String strLine;

//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console - do what you want to do
  System.out.println (strLine);
}

//Close the input stream
fstream.close();
```

To learn more about how to read file in Java, [check out the article](https://javatutorial.net/java-read-file-example).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, so I'll only answer for the "read" part :

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName"));
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null)
{
    lines.add(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Common used:

```
    String line = null;
    File file = new File( "readme.txt" );

    FileReader fr = null;
    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader( file );
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {  
        System.out.println( "File doesn't exists" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fr );

    try
    {
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
    {
        System.out.println( line );
    }
```

Comment: @Kamil After adding java import.io.* to the top and including the class, this worked fine for me except that the output to the cmd window has a space between each alphabet. How to avoid the spaces in the output.

Answer (score 0):

@user248921 first of all, you can store any text in string array , so you can make string array and store a line in array and use value in code whenever you want. you can use the below code to store heterogeneous(containing string, int, boolean,etc) lines in array.

```
public class user {
 public static void main(String x[]) throws IOException{
  BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<path to file>"));
  String[] user=new String[500];
  String line="";
  while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
   user[i]=line; 
   System.out.println(user[1]);
   i++;  
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: You cannot 'store anything in a String array'. You can only store Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PredmetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define the file path to read the subject names and grades from
        String filePath = "path_to_your_file.txt";

        // Create a list to store the subjects
        List<Predmet> predmeti = new ArrayList<>();

        // Read the file and populate the predmeti list
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                String subjectName = parts[0];

                // Parse the grades for the subject
                List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    grades.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[i]));
                }

                // Create a new Predmet object with the subject name and grades
                Predmet predmet = new Predmet(subjectName, grades);

                // Add the Predmet object to the list
                predmeti.add(predmet);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Calculate and display the average grade for each subject
        double highestAverage = -1;
        Predmet predmetWithHighestAverage = null;

        for (Predmet predmet : predmeti) {
            // Calculate the average grade for the subject
            double average = predmet.calculateAverage();

            // Update the subject with the highest average if necessary
            if (average > highestAverage) {
                highestAverage = average;
                predmetWithHighestAverage = predmet;
            }

            // Display the subject and its average grade
            System.out.println("Subject: " + predmet.getSubjectName());
            System.out.println("Average grade: " + average);
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Display the subject with the highest average grade
        if (predmetWithHighestAverage != null) {
            System.out.println("Subject with the highest average grade: " + predmetWithHighestAverage.getSubjectName());
        }
    }
}

public class Predmet {
    private String subjectName;
    private List<Integer> grades;

    public Predmet(String subjectName, List<Integer> grades) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }

    public double calculateAverage() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int grade : grades) {
            sum += grade;
        }
        return (double) sum / grades.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Predmet {
    String naziv;
    float ocjena;

    public Predmet(String naziv, float ocjena) {
        this.naziv = naziv;
        this.ocjena = ocjena;
    }
}

public class PredmetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Predmet> predmeti = new ArrayList<>();

        // Učitavanje predmeta iz datoteke
        try {
            File file = new File("predmeti.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                String naziv = parts[0];
                float ocjena = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
                Predmet predmet = new Predmet(naziv, ocjena);
                predmeti.add(predmet);
            }

            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Datoteka nije pronađena.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Ispisivanje predmeta i zaključne ocjene
        float najveciProsjek = 0;
        Predmet predmetSaNajvecimProsjekom = null;

        for (Predmet predmet : predmeti) {
            System.out.println("Predmet: " + predmet.naziv);
            System.out.println("Zaključna ocjena: " + predmet.ocjena);
            System.out.println();

            if (predmet.ocjena > najveciProsjek) {
                najveciProsjek = predmet.ocjena;
                predmetSaNajvecimProsjekom = predmet;
            }
        }

        // Ispisivanje predmeta s najvišim prosjekom
        if (predmetSaNajvecimProsjekom != null) {
            System.out.println("Predmet s najvišim prosjekom: " + predmetSaNajvecimProsjekom.naziv);
            System.out.println("Prosjek ocjena: " + predmetSaNajvecimProsjekom.ocjena);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice way to work with Streams and Collectors.

```
List<String> myList;
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourpath"))){
    myList = reader.lines() // This will return a Stream<String>
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When working with Streams you have also multiple methods to filter, manipulate or reduce your input.

Answer (score -1):

For **Java 11** you could use the next short approach:

```
  Path path = Path.of("file.txt");
  try (var reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
      }
  }
```

Or:

```
var path = Path.of("file.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or:

```
Files.lines(Path.of("file.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
```