# Questions on reading a generic text file in java

Tags: java, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a text file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049380/reading-a-text-file-in-java)

I have a generic text file, which can be composed of text data and numerical values, like an article. It can have multiple paragraphs/lines and have various types of delimiters. My general purpose is to tokenize this text file into a string array. I am quite confusing on how to handle this in Java, should I use “scanner” or “Bufferedreader”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either would be fine. If you're just reading lines, `Scanner` might be a bit of overkill.