# How do I read in a file and count characters?

Tags: java, file

I need help on how to start a Java class.

The class defines a method or methods that first reads in a file then reads its characters one by one. After doing this it is to see how many of those characters form words by looking for things like '.' and ' '. After all that, keep count of how many words and put them on a hashmap.

I know how to use a for loop to look for the ' ', ',', '.' etc. and keeping count of words

But I don't know how to read in a file that reads character by character a file.

My TA said something about the 'put' and 'get' method? no idea what they are :S

Therefore I know how to do pretty much everything except the beginning. sorry I can't show you a method of the second half before knowing how to do the first half.

Any help to get this started .. thanks!

Comment: looks like homework, smells like homework...

Comment: you can start by reading this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html

Comment: @mcfinnigan definitely homework (:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049380/reading-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: `put(K key, V value)` and `get(K key)` are methods from the `Map` interface (call them on your hashmap, for example)

Comment: It is homework, that I had a week to work on .. and I still don't understand it.
That's why i came here searching for help. If i didn't need help .. i wouldn't come here :P

Answer (score 1):

A `Reader` will allow you to read data character at a time (e.g. you could use an `InputStreamReader` together with a `FileInputStream` to read from a `File`)

Also make sure you specify the character encoding of the file you are reading, this ensures correct conversion from bytes to chars.

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("path/to/file"), "charset e.g. utf-8"));
```