# Reading data from text line by line in java

Tags: java, save, file-read, 2d-games

I'm making a game in Java, but can't figure out how to get information from a text file so that I can load the game. I have the saved files set up so that on every line there is the name of a method in my Main program. What I need to do is to look in a certain line for text and execute the method that the text is referring to.

Comment: please clear your question a little bit more.BTW you can use property file or your own config files for this purpose

Comment: Do you want to know "How can i read file in java?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  Obviously you'll need to handle exceptions:

```
public class FileReaderTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException
  {
    final FileReaderTest object = new FileReaderTest(); 

    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file")));
    for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    {
      object.getClass().getMethod(line).invoke(object);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is assuming that you are talking about a .txt file.
I/O is the basic Idea, If you master that, then you are set. I stands for input, and O, for Output.

Now, you need to make an variable equal to inputStream.readInt();

EDIT:

But for more help, you can also go with reading 
[Reading a text file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049380/reading-a-text-file-in-java)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh yeah, and one more thing, not to be mean, but I don't know that you are ready for game programming just yet. If you must, keep trying JPanel, JFrame, ect. but stick to the basics for a month or so, then you won't even need anyone here!